# What is the use of a ForwardingMap in Guava?

Tags: java, guava

I am scratching my head over understanding the use of a ForwardingMap?
What are the cases that one might use it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ForwardingXxx` classes provide [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) implementations for all JDK and Guava collections, including `Map`.

Read more on [Guava's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#Forwarding_Decorators) and in *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*:

> To summarize, inheritance is powerful, but it is problematic because
>   it violates encapsulation. It is appropriate only when a genuine
>   subtype relationship exists between the subclass and the superclass.
>   Even then, inheritance may lead to fragility if the subclass is in a
>   different package from the superclass and the superclass is not
>   designed for inheritance. To avoid this fragility, use composition and
>   forwarding instead of inheritance, especially if an appropriate
>   interface to implement a wrapper class exists. Not only are wrapper
>   classes more robust than subclasses, they are also more powerful.

Basically it lets you customize possibly non-extendable `Map`s without adding dependencies on actual `Map` implementation.

Comment: I'd add another +1 for the Effective Java reference

Answer (score 4):

The default Map classes are all final. That means you can't extend them. When you want to create a map with some special behavior, you need to write your own class which implements the whole Map interface and forwards all methods to an internal Map.

The ForwardingMap makes this simpler for you by already being an extendable class which implements Map and forwards everything to an internal map. That means you can create your own Map implementation by extending it. When you do that, you only need to implement selected methods and not all of them.

One use-case might be a map which automatically validates all entries you put into it or one which automatically updates a database when it's changed.

Comment: HashMap isn't final. LinkedHashMap extends it, and that isn't final either.